# Are there any security implications to leaving Firefox's advanced developer tools enabled?

Tags: web-browser, firefox, browser-hijacking

Mozilla's Firefox web browser has two advanced developer tools settings that are disabled by default.

To enable them, open the Developer Tools settings, go to the section *"Advanced Settings"*, and check *"Enable browser chrome and add-on debugging toolboxes"* and *"Enable remote debugging"*.

This enables Firefox's [Browser Toolbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Tools/Browser_Toolbox), which I find incredibly useful.

What are the security implications, if any, of leaving either, or both of those settings enabled?  If you can address each setting individually, and in combination, that would be most appreciated.

Comment: 1. you can view/mess with extensions from devtools. 2. you can mess with devtools remotely. 3. you can mess with extensions remotely.

Comment: @dandavis Thanks.  I'm not sure if #1 is a security issue.  #2 and #3 require accepting a very large and unique prompt.  Let's assume you are the only one with physical access to the machine, and so you won't accept that prompt randomly.